# Unable to locate an executable at "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.4.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/apt" (-1) when running sudo

Tags: java, macos, terminal, sudo

When I run

```
sudo apt install gzip
```

I get the following error:

```
Unable to locate an executable at "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.4.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/apt" (-1)
```

None of the solutions from other questions solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the apt tool is not present anymore in the java version you have.

Try using [referece](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-gzip)

```
npm install node-gzip --save
```

I suggest you read the [original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61847827/10907417) given by @Axel to a similar question.
For simplicity, I quote it here:

> Sorry, I just saw what's wrong...
>
> There used to be an `apt` tool in Java, but it's gone now. Your
> mistake is using the linux command line. On many linux systems,
> another tool called `apt` is used for installing software.
>
> Check the `npm` documentation on how to install `nom` on your Mac, as
> there are different ways to do it.
>
> Once `npm` is installed, run `sudo npm install -g express-generator`
> (no `apt` here).
>
> - **Explanation of the error message**
>
>   The Java apt-tool was [removed](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/117) in JDK 8. But as JAVA_HOME/bin is normally not on your PATH on Mac, apple provides simple wrappers
>   for all the commands under JAVA_HOME. There still is such a wrapper
>   for `apt` that tries to run a program with the same name from your
>   Java installation. That's why you get that error message.
> - **conflict between the pre-installed macOS Java-Version and the Orcalce Java-Version:**
>
>   Apple [stopped pre-installing Java in macOS 10.7](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/102466/does-java-come-pre-installed-on-mac-os-x-10-7-10-8-and-beyond/102548) so this should not be an issue.
> - **difference between java_home and JAVA_HOME:**
>
>   JAVA_HOME is an environment variable that points to your Java installation. `java_home` is a utility program in macOS that makes it
>   easier to correctly set up your JAVA_HOME by listing installed Java
>   versions and the values to use for JAVA_HOME.