# Unable to locate an executable at "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/..."

Tags: java, macos

I want to install an NPM express generator:

`sudo apt npm install -g  express-generator`

It throws the following error:

`Unable to locate an executable at "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-14.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/apt" (-1)`

I installed Java in this path (it's not in the System/Library/ - maybe thats the issue?):

'MacintoshSSD/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-14.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home'

My .bash_profile looks like that:

`export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)`

If I check JAVA_HOME it looks fine:

`echo $JAVA_HOME
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-14.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home`

.. and Java version:

`java --version
openjdk 14.0.1 2020-04-14
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 14.0.1+7)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 14.0.1+7, mixed mode, sharing)`

Any idea why it still can find an exectuable?

I an other thread I read about a possible conflict between the pre-installed macOS Java-Version and the Orcalce Java-Version [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18144853/11720573) but I couldn`t work it out..

And could you explain to me the difference between java_home and JAVA_HOME?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry, I just saw what's wrong...

There used to be an `apt` tool in Java, but it's gone now. Your mistake is using the linux command line. On many linux systems, another tool called `apt` is used for installing software.

Check the `npm` documentation on how to install `npm` on your Mac, as there are different ways to do it.

Once `npm` is installed, run `sudo npm install -g express-generator` (no `apt` here).

- **Explanation of the error message**

  The Java apt-tool was [removed](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/117) in JDK 8. But as JAVA_HOME/bin is normally not on your PATH on Mac, apple provides simple wrappers for all the commands under JAVA_HOME. There still is such a wrapper for `apt` that tries to run a program with the same name from your Java installation. That's why you get that error message.
- **conflict between the pre-installed macOS Java-Version and the Orcalce Java-Version:**

  Apple [stopped pre-installing Java in macOS 10.7](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/102466/does-java-come-pre-installed-on-mac-os-x-10-7-10-8-and-beyond/102548) so this should not be an issue.
- **difference between java_home and JAVA_HOME:**

  JAVA_HOME is an environment variable that points to your Java installation. `java_home` is a utility program in macOS that makes it easier to correctly set up your JAVA_HOME by listing installed Java versions and the values to use for JAVA_HOME.

Comment: Thank you so much! I wasted hours, because I thought it is an issue with Java ..

Comment: "how to install nom on your Mac" -- did you mean `npm`?